# How to apply OpenSSL patch to Ubuntu system?

Tags: python, openssl, ubuntu-16.04

I'm having trouble rununning `pip install -r requirements.txt` on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm getting this error:

```
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:697:6: error: conflicting types for ‘BIO_new_mem_buf’
```

I was checking some forums and some Gentoo guys posted [this link](http://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/commit/?id=fe3faddb9bf793b16a104bc5f0d304f14e8cf057) with the solution but I don't know how to run it on my computer:

```
diff --git a/dev-python/cryptography/cryptography-1.2.2.ebuild b/dev-python/cryptography/cryptography-1.2.2.ebuild
index ae9dbd1..af7e5a1 100644
--- a/dev-python/cryptography/cryptography-1.2.2.ebuild
+++ b/dev-python/cryptography/cryptography-1.2.2.ebuild
@@ -43,6 +43,8 @@ DEPEND="${RDEPEND}

 DOCS=( AUTHORS.rst CONTRIBUTING.rst README.rst )

+PATCHES=( "${FILESDIR}/${PN}-1.2.2-openssl-1.0.2g-mem_buf.patch" )
+
 python_test() {
    py.test -v -v -x || die "Tests fail with ${EPYTHON}"
 }
diff --git a/dev-python/cryptography/files/cryptography-1.2.2-openssl-1.0.2g-mem_buf.patch b/dev-python/cryptography/files/cryptography-1.2.2-openssl-1.0.2g-mem_buf.patch
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..64d270b
--- /dev/null
+++ b/dev-python/cryptography/files/cryptography-1.2.2-openssl-1.0.2g-mem_buf.patch
@@ -0,0 +1,12 @@
+diff -ru cryptography-1.2.2/src/_cffi_src/openssl/bio.py cryptography-1.2.2-fixed/src/_cffi_src/openssl/bio.py
+--- cryptography-1.2.2/src/_cffi_src/openssl/bio.py    2016-01-29 20:26:11.000000000 +0100
++++ cryptography-1.2.2-fixed/src/_cffi_src/openssl/bio.py  2016-03-01 20:32:25.172776288 +0100
+@@ -99,7 +99,7 @@
+ BIO *BIO_next(BIO *);
+ BIO *BIO_find_type(BIO *, int);
+ BIO_METHOD *BIO_s_mem(void);
+-BIO *BIO_new_mem_buf(void *, int);
++BIO *BIO_new_mem_buf(const void *, int);
+ BIO_METHOD *BIO_s_file(void);
+ BIO *BIO_new_file(const char *, const char *);
+ BIO *BIO_new_fp(FILE *, int);
```

How do I manually apply the OpenSSL patch to an Ubuntu system?

Thanks.

Comment: There is literally only a single line in that patch. Do you know how to use a text editor?

Comment: yes but im not sure what i am suppose to do with this line

Answer (score 0):

To run this script in the comment I had create a patch file `patch foo.c < patch.diff`

You can get more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228422/diff-option-not-recognize-git/37228839#37228839)