# diff: option not recognize «--git»

Tags: git, python-2.7, cryptography, diff, ubuntu-16.04

When I'm trying to install depencies for a python script I get this error:

```
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:697:6: error: conflicting types for ‘BIO_new_mem_buf’
 BIO *BIO_new_mem_buf(void *, int);
      ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:65:0,
                 from build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:413:
/usr/include/openssl/bio.h:692:6: note: previous declaration of ‘BIO_new_mem_buf’ was here
 BIO *BIO_new_mem_buf(const void *buf, int len);
      ^
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I try this patch found [here](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/commit/?id=fe3faddb9bf793b16a104bc5f0d304f14e8cf057):

```
diff --git a/dev-python/cryptography/cryptography-1.2.2.ebuild b/dev-python/cryptography/cryptography-1.2.2.ebuild
```

But then I get this error `diff: option not recognize «--git»`

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`diff --git` is not a command, but the [header of a `git diff -p`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) (patch):

> What the `-p` option produces is slightly different from the traditional diff format:
>
> It is preceded with a "git diff" header that looks like this:

```
diff --git a/file1 b/file2
```

Since the diffstat in the gentoo repo is in unified mode, you can copy it in a patch file, and [apply it to your codebase](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-867029-start-0.html) with a [`patch` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch).
(See [more examples here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appy-patch-file-using-patch-command/)).

```
patch foo.c < patch.diff
```

Comment: I created my .diff file and run `patch foo.c < patch.diff`.. I'm getting this message 
`patching file foo.c`
`Hunk #1 FAILED at 43.`
`1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file foo.c.rej`